# How to retrieve recursive information in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In my Apex Application there is the opportunity to set filters for creating a chart. A user can choose several systems if he wants to. The systems are created as a checkbox item. The source of the checkbox item is based on a list of values which contains a SQL Query to retrieve all systems out of my database table. Here is the structure of my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE system_table (
system_id                  NUMBER(16) NOT NULL,
system_name                VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL,
system_table_uebergeordnet_ID NUMBER(16),
CONSTRAINT system_name_unique UNIQUE(system_name),
CONSTRAINT system_table_pk PRIMARY KEY ( system_id ),
CONSTRAINT system_table_uber_id_fk FOREIGN KEY ( system_table_uebergeordnet_ID )
    REFERENCES system_table ( system_id )   );
```

As you can see in the code, the last attribute is a recursive relationship. What I want to have now is the following: If a user selects a system_name and submits the page, the system name and all other systems that are referencing the chosen system should be selected. Therefore I have created a hidden item called System_ID. Before submitting the page I have defined a dynamic action which picks up the id of the chosen system_name. After submitting the page, my chart is created and I am checking for the condition in a where-clause. It looks like that:

```
where ((instr(':' || upper(:P26_SYSTEMS) || ':', upper(SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_NAME)) > 0) or (instr(':' || upper(:P26_SYSTEMS_ALL) || ':', upper(SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_NAME)) > 0) or (SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_TABLE_UEBERGEORDNET_ID = :P26_SYSTEM_ID))
```

The query is working so far, but only selects the chosen system_name and not the systems who are referencing the chosen system. I hope I was able to explain the problem and you can understand it. Does anyone of you know what I am doing wrong here?

The following code shows my query:

```
select COUNT(TRIGGER_TABLE.DATUM_UHRZEIT) as Anzahl_Trigger,
       TEST.NUMMER as NUMMER
from BRIDGE_SYSTEM_TRIGGER, SYSTEM_TABLE, TRIGGER_TABLE, FAHRT, TEST, MITARBEITER
where BRIDGE_SYSTEM_TRIGGER.SYSTEM_TABLE_SYSTEM_ID = SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_ID
      and BRIDGE_SYSTEM_TRIGGER.TRIGGER_TABLE_TRIGGER_ID = TRIGGER_TABLE.TRIGGER_ID
      and TRIGGER_TABLE.FAHRT_FAHRT_ID = FAHRT.FAHRT_ID
      and MITARBEITER.NUMMER = FAHRT.MITARBEITER_NUMMER
      and FAHRT.TEST_ID= TEST_ID
      and TRIGGER_TABLE.PRIORITAET = 1
      and ((instr(':' || upper(:P26_TEST) || ':', upper(TEST.TEST_ID)) > 0) or (instr(':' || upper(:P26_TEST_ALL) || ':', upper(TEST.TEST_ID)) > 0))
      and ((instr(':' || upper(:P26_SYSTEMS) || ':',':' || upper(system_table.system_name) ||':') > 0)  or (instr(':' || upper(:P26_SYSTEMS_ALL) || ':', upper(SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_NAME)) > 0) or exists (select child.system_id from system_table child where  instr(':' || upper(:P26_SYSTEMS) ||':',':'|| upper(child.system_name) ||':') > 0 and child.system_table_uebergeordnet_id = system_table.system_id))
      and ((instr(':' || upper(:P26_COUNTRIES) || ':', upper(FAHRT.LAND)) > 0) or (instr(':' || upper(:P26_COUNTRIES_ALL) || ':', upper(FAHRT.LAND)) > 0))
      and ((instr(':' || upper(:P26_FAHRER) || ':', upper(MITARBEITER.QNUMMER)) > 0) or (instr(':' || upper(:P26_FAHRER_ALL) || ':', upper(MITARBEITER.QNUMMER)) > 0))
GROUP BY TEST.NUMMMER
ORDER BY TEST.NUMMER;
```

The query counts the number of triggers per priority ordered by Testnumbers. **The triggers that are meant here have nothing to do with sql triggers! So please don't be confused about that term.**
A 'Fahrt' belongs to one 'Test' and a 'Test' can contain several 'Fahrten'.  Furthermore each 'Fahrt' contains several triggers. The last four where conditions are the mentioned conditions to retrieve the filterinformation that have been set and only those triggers that met the filter conditions are counted.

Comment: By the way, you should be able to get rid of the dependence on system names and have the list of values return the `system_id` instead of needing a DA to set the hidden item.

Comment: Yes I know that you are absolutely right, but I didn't know how to that. If I am using the system_id as my return value the filter is not working anymore. It only works when I am using the system name. This is how the list of values query looks like:

`select distinct(SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_NAME) as display_value,
        SYSTEM_TABLE.SYSTEM_NAME as return_value
from SYSTEM_TABLE order by system_table.system_name`

Comment: Obviously if you change the return value of the list item, you need to update your query accordingly to accept system_id values instead of system names. But it will work better that way because it won't fail in case a system name happens to include an embedded colon (`:`).

Comment: You have a lot of (effectively) inner joins and predicates that might be filtering out results you expect. Take the query, comment-out all the bits that are not relevant, and test it. If the results you expect appear, gradually add one bit back in one at a time until they disappear again - then you'll know which predicate or join is removing the results that you expect.

Comment: All filters are working well except the System-Filter. That's why I started the thread.

Comment: I suggest you whittle it down to the simplest possible form, and build a test case on livesql.oracle.com. Otherwise we can only guess what the problem might be.

Answer (score 2):

A hierarchical data structure can be queried using a hierarchical query. In Oracle you can use something like this (note: not tested):

```
select ...
from system_table
where instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
           ,':'||upper(system_table.system_name)||':') > 0
or system_table.system_id in (
  select parent.system_id
  from   system_table parent
  start with instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
                  ,':'||upper(parent.system_name)||':') > 0
  connect by prior parent.system_table_uebergeordnet_id = parent.system_id
)
```

This hierarchical query starts from the selected system name(s) and walks up the hierarchy to their parents, grandparents, etc. to the top. The resulting set of system IDs is then used to filter the main table.

If you need it to select any children of a selected system, switch the `connect by` clause, e.g.

```
select ...
from system_table
where instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
           ,':'||upper(system_table.system_name)||':') > 0
or system_table.system_id in (
  select parent.system_id
  from   system_table parent
  start with instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
                  ,':'||upper(parent.system_name)||':') > 0
  connect by prior parent.system_id = parent.system_table_uebergeordnet_id
)
```

On the third hand, if it's not a multi-level hierarchy you can make the query simpler, e.g.

```
select ...
from system_table
where instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
           ,':'||upper(system_table.system_name)||':') > 0
or exists (
  select child.system_id
  from   system_table child
  where  instr(':'||upper(:P26_SYSTEMS)||':'
              ,':'||upper(parent.system_name)||':') > 0
  and    child.system_table_uebergeordnet_id = system_table.system_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it a try. So far it is compiling and I am getting some results, but unfortunately they are not correct yet. Maybe I should add the following information: The maximum level of my hierarchy is 1 that means I only have parents and childs. parents are not referencing any other system. What is the start with and connect by statement doing? Furthermore I am selecting parent systems so I need to know the children of the parent. That may be why the query is not working so far because your solution is currently doing it the other way round, doesn't it?

Comment: That's right, my hierarchical query starts from the child and works its way to the parent. I'll update the answer accordingly. Also, if you are only interested in parents and children, that means it's not really an interesting hierarchy so you don't need a hierarchical query.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the last query you have posted and still getting not the right result in my opinion. Unfortunately I don't have any idea where my mistake happens in the query. The query you have posted makes absolutely sense in my opinion! Could it be a problem for the query if my parent contains NULL in the attribute 'system_table_uebergeordnet_id'? Because that is the case right now although all other children contain the right values. And in my opinion it also doesn't make any sense that a parent contains a value in that attribute. So I think that actually should be right..

Comment: I'd expect that parents should have NULL for the parent ID column. I'm not sure what you're expecting otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's what I am expecting as well. Shouldn't be a problem for the query.

Comment: Furthermore I checked the following: I selected the children and the parent --> result of my created chart is correct.
When selecting only the parent --> result of chart is not correct, because only the parent is selected and not the children, although I added the suggested query which makes sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post your entire query, along with some sample data. I recommend using livesql.oracle.com to build a test case with expected/actual results.

Comment: Ok I will add my query to my post at the top of the page. Would be nice if you can take a look.